# passing parameters containing # in URL for calling webservice using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am calling one of my **webservice** in which im sending some paramters like key,id,subject line,etc

```
example:
 http://asv.msdasmafetrix.net/public/mobile.ashx?method=getparsedtemplate_contactinfo&emailbody='" + emailbody + "'&subjectline='" + subjectline + "'&contactemailid=" + contactemailid + "&id=" + jasondata.id + "&key=" + jasondata.key
```

but,in parameters like subject and emailbody `#` variable is present due to which it is breaking my code.and giving me undefined value.i have even tried encodeURI.got no success though.

my code is:

```
var uri="http://asv.msdasmafetrix.net/public/mobile.ashx?method=getparsedtemplate_contactinfo&emailbody='" + emailbody + "'&subjectline='" + subjectline + "'&contactemailid=" + contactemailid + "&id=" + jasondata.id + "&key=" + jasondata.key";
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: encodeURI(uri),
        success: function(msg) {
            jasondata = eval('(' + msg + ')');
            var subjectline = jasondata.subjectline;
            alert(subjectline);
            }
    });
```

any help ...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `encodeURIComponent(uri)`

[Documentation for encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: i have encoded two components i.e. subject line and image while adding them in uri using encodeuricomponent.still not working?\